# Exporting click coordinates Windows or Photoshop

Tags: windows, mouse, photoshop

I would like to export click coordinates on an image to a text file, for processing later in another application.  Example of format below, will be easy to manipulate once generated of course.

```
101, 25
200, 31
77, 252
```

Ideally in Photoshop but actually if I just position the image at 0,0 on my screen, I would be able to use an Windows application to do this, so I think either is fine.

Does anyone know a Photoshop Plugin / Windows application to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain about specific applications for any location on a screen, however, there are quite a few img map tools available that may be able to help you with an export of the coordinates.

This tool is by far the most versatile that I have found:

["Summer" HTML img Map](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/s/u/summerstyle/365ccfd644f2b008c33f0046d2ba1a8f/summer-html-image-ma_1355318513_demo_package/index.html)

Here are a few other tools I have used:

http://www.image-maps.com/

http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap

http://www.html-map.com/

...Also, there are a few firefox plugins you can install to help with click areas... you may be able to get the coordinates in a txt file from them:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ime/